# Button On/Off sound in settings

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have two ViewController (ViewController and Settings). How can I do that when Switch was turned off the sound of the buttons (or in the application) was turned off and turned on ??

**Code for the sound of the buttons:**

```
@IBAction func SoundButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let filename = "button-16"
    let ext = "mp3"

    if let soundUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: ext) {
        var soundId: SystemSoundID = 0

        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundUrl as CFURL, &soundId)

        AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(soundId, nil, nil, { (soundId, clientData) -> Void in
            AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundId)
        }, nil)

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question, can you describe in more detail?

Comment: @AnhPham It is necessary that when the Switch is turned off, the sound of the buttons is turned off

Answer (score 0):

Take global `boolean` variable `isSound` for the `UISwitch`. When `UISwitch` is `on` means `true`, make the variable `isSound on`. Now, make the condition based on variable.

You can make a global variable with `AppDelegate` file or header file. (`.h file`)

```
if isSound == true || isSound == on {
// make sound on
} else {
// make sound off
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In My Code i am play Text to Speech Sound And Manage**

```
    var speedd = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        var voicert = AVSpeechUtterance()
var Strdata = "This is Sound for Music"
        override func viewDidLoad()
            {
                super.viewDidLoad()

        voicert = AVSpeechUtterance(string:Strdata)
        voicert.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
         voicert.rate = 0.5
        }
        @IBAction func switchSound(_ sender: UISwitch)
            {

                if sender.isOn
                {
                    speedd.speak(voicert)
                }
                else
                {
                   speedd.stopSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.immediate)
                }

            }
```